# How to export query results from TFS 2013 Issue tracker web ui?

Tags: tfs

I have access to TFS 2013 Issue Tracker Web UI, only option i see to export my query results is to send them as an email. Is there any other way to export them to more "computer" friendly format? I would like to use those results as input in my application.

**Edit:** Some more information. My TFS version is 12.0.40629.0. I don't have Visual Studio and my Excel does'n have tab "Team" on the ribbon. Let's assume that i don't have any rights to install additional applications, all i have is Web UI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [REST APIs for queries](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/wit/overview) to get the results of a query if you want to consume the data by a tool. These APIs should be available on TFS 2015.

There is also a [suggestion on user voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/4152668-export-to-excel-from-web-access) requesting to add Excel export to the Web

Answer (score 0):

You can only export query result by sending it as an email from Web access. But you can export the query result to Excel from Team Explorer:

[image]

Another way is saving the query from Web Access, then create report from Excel directly by clicking `Team` tab and go to `New List` to connect the team project and select the saved query result:

[image]

Comment: I updated some information. For now only way is to send email, but it's not very convenient. Is't there any way to get JSON or at least CSV from query results?

Comment: There is no such option on Web Access by default.